# Selenium-Wire Your Connection Is Not Secure

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium-wire with undetectable chromedriver and it's giving me: "Your Connection To This Site Is Not Secure" when I go into a site, and the **https** in the website address is crossed over, and it's saying that the certificate is invalid. The website's certificate is, however, not invalid. When I go into the website on my normal browser, it works as it should. I have noticed this happening on all https websites, i.e. **https://httpbin.org/headers** and **https://google.com/**, etc.

```
import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as uc
if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    driver = uc.Chrome(
        options=options,
        seleniumwire_options={}
    )

    driver.get('https://httpbin.org/headers')
```

This doesn't give me a popup or anything and I can still use the site normally, but I would like to get it fixed.
How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [mre] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. Without more concrete detail, we can only speculate on the cause.

Answer (score 9):

Install the certificate in chrome. You can get the certificate using `python -m seleniumwire extractcert` or you can download that from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/master/seleniumwire/proxy/ca.crt
How to install the certificate.

- Open Chrome settings
- Search Manage Certificates and open that
- Click on “Trusted Root Certification Authorities”
- Import the certificate you just have downloaded.

Comment: no need to download the certificate, it is already there in site packege > seleniumwire
just double click on that and it will be imported in your system keychain, click always trust

Comment: I tried installing the way @InzamamMalik said but it did not work.
Had to follow through the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The Certificate has been moved from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/master/seleniumwire/proxy/ca.crt to https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/raw/master/seleniumwire/ca.crt

Source: https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/120#issuecomment-877845102

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using `python -m seleniumwire extractcert` and setup chrome browser is the good approach.
But if you want to automate this, you can also run:

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t TC -n "Selenium Wire" -i /path/to/ca.crt
```

To pragmatically fix the certificate issue without having to manually edit chrome setup.